# Gather stats on subpartitioned tables in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

There is a table that gets updated by multiple batches running in parallel. i.e., 
  -  the application runs an analysis, which has an analysis id and 
  -  this analysis inserts data into a table "ANALYSIS_TABLE" in batches and
  -  each batch has a batch id
I need to gather statistics on this table "ANALYSIS_TABLE" when each batch is finished.

The structure of the table is:

```
Analysis_id | Batch_id | Analysis_Val | Specific_key |
----------- |  ------  | ------------ | ------------
A1          |    B1    |     2.0      |     A1-B1    |
A1          |    B1    |     5.0      |     A1-B1    |
```

I need to call gather statistics like, 
     call pack_stats.gather_table_stats('ANALYSIS_TABLE','A1-B1') ,

```
 call pack_stats.gather_table_stats('ANALYSIS_TABLE','A1-B2') (*if it has a 
 value for specific_key column like 'A1-B2'*)

 and so on.
```

But when I call this, oracle does not identify the keys 'A1-B1' , 'A1-B2' etc.

The table 'ANALYSIS_TABLE' is a subpartitioned table.
Executing the below query shows the subpartition_key which has no relation to the data in 'Specific_key' column :

```
*select table_name, partition_name,subpartition_name, last_analyzed, 
 num_rows from user_tab_statistics where table_name='ANALYSIS_TABLE' and 
 partition_name='P000000000563'*
```

```
Table_name    | partition_name | subpartition_name   | last_analyzed | num_rows|
--------------| -------------- | -----------------   | ------------- | -------- 
ANALYSIS_TABLE | P000000000563 | (null)               | 04-Apr-17     |   2   |
ANALYSIS_TABLE | P000000000563 | P000000000563_null   | 04-Apr-17     |   0   |
ANALYSIS_TABLE | P000000000563 | P000000000563_DEFAULT| 04-Apr-17     |   2   |
```

How can I make sure that the values in 'specific_key' column in my first table is reflected in the subpartition_name column of user_tab_statistics ?

or rather how to make a relation between 'specific_key' column and the subpartition_name column.

Any other ideas on gathering statistics for each batch as I have mentioned is also welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The straight forward approach would be this:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, PARTITION_NAME, SUBPARTITION_NAME, HIGH_VALUE
FROM USER_TAB_SUBPARTITIONS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'ANALYSIS_TABLE' 
    AND PARTITION_NAME = 'P000000000563'
    AND HIGH_VALUE = 'A1-B2';
```

However, you will get an

> ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype

`LONG` data type is deprecated for ages but Oracle himself is using it a lot!

A workaround is this one:

```
DECLARE

    KeyValue ANALYSIS_TABLE.Specific_key%TYPE;

    CURSOR TabSubPartitions IS
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, PARTITION_NAME, SUBPARTITION_NAME, HIGH_VALUE
    FROM USER_TAB_SUBPARTITIONS 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'ANALYSIS_TABLE' 
        AND PARTITION_NAME = 'P000000000563';

BEGIN
    FOR aSubPart IN TabSubPartitions LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := '||aSubPart.HIGH_VALUE||'; END;' USING OUT KeyValue;
        IF KeyValue = 'A1-B1' THEN
            DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(USER, 'ANALYSIS_TABLE', aSubPart.SUBPARTITION_NAME);
        END IF;     
    END LOOP;
END;
```